# Angular: Add product as favorite

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm currently trying to learn Angular and i have a list of products, and every product can be favorited which puts them in a menu called "Favorites" (What it really does is inserts a row in db, when clicked again it removes from db).

The functionality is done, i just want the button to have two "states" (when a product is favorited it should be yellow, and when its not favorited it should be transparent).

So somehow the link must check the controller which returns true or false depending on if the product exists in db, table: Part_Favorites.

CSS:

```
 .active { background:yellow;}
 .inactive { background:transparent;)
```

HTML:

```
 <a ng-click="myfavorites()">Add favorites</a>
```

Controller

```
$scope.myfavorites = function (parts) {

    CategoryService.myfavorites(parts, function (callback) {
        //$route.reload();
        window.location.reload(false);
    });

    if ($scope.loading == false) {
        item.Checked == true ? item.Checked = false : item.Checked = true;
        $scope.loopFilters();
        $rootScope.loading = true;
        $location.url('/Category/' + $routeParams.id + '/' + $scope.url);
    }
};
```

Service:

```
        myfavorites: function (data, callback) {
        $http.post(shopID + '/Product/MyFavourites?SalesPartNo=' + data).success(function (data) {
            callback(data)
        }).error(function (data) {
            callback(data);
        });
    },
```

EDIT: Updated my post with Service. Still need help!

The code works, and it inserts/deletes into a favorite menu. But how do i make it so it changes class on the button depending if its favorited or not?

Comment: I still cant get it to work correctly. Anyone?
Either all of them gets favorited or none.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a ng-click="myfavorites()" ng-class="{active: item.Checked, inactive: !item.Checked}">Add favorites</a>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution howerver using item.Checked doesnt seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: it has to be available in the scope, it's not clear from your code where the item variable is coming from, so I don't know if it is or isn't available as a scope variable

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code a little bit:

```
item.Checked = !item.Checked;
item.className = item.Checked ? "active" : "inactive";
```

I believe you could print the class directly inside your template:

```
{{className}}
```

So it would just update it on the front end automatically.

Comment: The class name is presentation, and so shouldn't be stored in the scope. Better to use `ng-class` in this case, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class in here.

When you retriving the items get the favorite information too.

```
$scope.retrieveItems = function() {
    //get the items with their favorite information(isFavorite [true,false])
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<a ng-click="myfavorites()" ng-class="{'active':item.isFavorite, 'inactive':!item.isFavoirte"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have a problem. Either all returns false or true, must be something wrong in my controller.